# Deleting a node from Linked List having "sentinels"

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write a Linked List having sentinels as per the CLRS book. My remove function for some reason removes a chunk of LL upto the node to be deleted. Attached is my code. Any suggestion will be deeply appreciated.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,v):
        self.value = v
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def changeValue(self,v):
        self.value = v

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def getPrev(self):
        return self.prev

    def setNext(self,newNext):
        self.next = newNext

    def setPrev(self,newPrev):
        self.prev = newPrev

class List(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nil = Node(None)

    def addNode(self,v):
        a = Node(v)
        a.setNext(self.nil.next)
        a.setPrev(self.nil)
        self.nil.next = a

    def length(self):
        count = 0
        a = self.nil
        while(a.next != None):
            count += 1
            a = a.getNext()
        return count

    def search(self,v):
        a = self.nil
        while(a.next != None):
            if (a.value == v):
                return True
            a = a.getNext()
        return False

    def remove(self,v):
        a = self.nil.next
        breakloop = 0
        while((a.next != None) and (breakloop == 0)):
            if (a.value == v):
                a.prev.next = a.next
                a.next.prev = a.prev
                breakloop = 1
            a = a.getNext()

    def printList(self):
        a = self.nil.next
        while(a.next != None):
            print(a.value)
            a =a.getNext()
        print(a.value)


a = List()
a.addNode(4)
a.addNode(7)
a.addNode(2)
a.addNode(6)
a.addNode(5)
a.addNode(8)
a.addNode(1)
a.addNode(14)
a.addNode(13)
a.addNode(17)
a.addNode(18)
a.printList()
a.remove(13)
a.printList()
```

The output will be
18 17 13 14 1 8 5 6 2 7 4
14 1 8 5 6 2 7 4

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I get that result running this code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I do not understand your comment.  The output listed appears to be in fact the output of the program (whereas the "desired" output is presumably the same except with the second set of results preceded by 18 17)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams- I don't understand what you mean sir. I am printing the output straight away.(All numbers are on a newline. I just used two here to denote List.print() being called twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in your `addNode` function, the `.prev` node for *all* of your nodes is `self.nil`

Using the following:

```
def addNode(self,v):
    a = Node(v)
    a.setNext(self.nil.next)
    if self.nil.next is not None:
        self.nil.next.setPrev(a)
    a.setPrev(self.nil)
    self.nil.next = a
```

will fix your problem.  You probably want to put this logic in the `setPrev` and `setNext` functions (to make sure `a == a.next.prev` and `a == a.prev.next` at all times for all `a` except the ends).

Comment: You can avoid the checks for `None` if you set `self.nil.next = self.nil.prev = self.nil` in the `List` class constructor. The list will be circular always, even when it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

@tcaswell has correctly diagnosed the problem with the code: you're not setting the `prev` links on the node that used to be `self.nil.next` correctly. However, I think his solution is not ideal. Here's what I suggest instead:

Here's the immediate fix to the issue:

```
def addNode(self, v):
    a = Node(v)

    a.setNext(self.nil.next)
    self.nil.next.setPrev(a) # this is the link that was previously missing

    a.setPrev(self.nil)
    self.nil.setNext(a)
```

However, that won't work correctly when the list is empty, since `self.nil.next` is `None` at the start. We can fix it though, by making `self.nil` link to itself when we create it in the `List` constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.nil = Node(None)
    self.nil.next = self.nil.prev = self.nil # set up circular links!
```

Now, `self.nil` will always have a valid node as it's `next` and `prev` values.

You will need to change your `removeNode` and `printList` loops to check for `self.nil` rather than `None`.